# Adding functional checkboxes to a list of users in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I imagine this is a common scenario but not finding any examples as to how to make this work in Vue.

I am fetching a list of users from a REST service and displaying the results in a table. (simplified below)

```
  <tr v-for="guser in filteredUsers" class="group_user">
      <td><input type="checkbox" v-bind="guser.checked"></td><td>{{guser.username}</td>
   </tr>
```

Now the problem is that the checked attribute is not a real attribute on the user object coming from the backend dataservice. So I am adding it on the client after fetching the list of users.
This seems like the correct approach because the backend service doesn't care about "checked" which is used for front end functionality.

However the binding of v-bind="guser.checked" does not work.
Reading up it seems this is because any attribute that is going to bound to a form control needs to be pre-defined when declaring the objects.
But how do i do that on a dynamic list of N objects that are coming back from the server?

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the checked property to your user objects after they have been retrieved via AJAX.

```js
console.clear()

// simulated data from the server
const users = [
  {id: 1, username: "Bob"},
  {id: 1, username: "Mary"},
]

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    users:[]
  },
  computed:{
    filteredUsers(){
      // simulate filtered users
      return this.users
    }
  },
  methods:{
    getUsers(){
      // simulate an ajax call with setTimeout
      setTimeout(() => {
        // iterate over the user objects retrieve from the server
        // and add a checked property. Assign the result to users
        this.users = users.map(u => Object.assign({}, u, {checked: false}))
      }, 250)
    }
  },
  created(){
    this.getUsers()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="guser in filteredUsers" class="group_user">
      <td><input type="checkbox"v-model="guser.checked"></td>
      <td>{{guser.username}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  {{users}}
</div>
```

The reason it doesn't work initially is because [Vue cannot detect](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) properties dynamically added to an object after that object has already been added to Vue. Another way to handle this would be to use the [`$set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set) method to add the property (instead of Object.assign as I do in the example).

Comment: Exactly what I needed thank you!
I noticed that you are using v-model in the checkbox. I would have expected to use v-bind - but that didnt work. What is the difference?

Comment: @Gotts `v-bind` will only set the input's value, you have to listen to the `input` event in order to change Vue's data value. `v-model` is the standard way to do both of these at the same time. Generally, whenever you have an input element, you will use `v-model` to get/set the value of the input. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events